# PHP returns HTML rather than JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, zend-framework

I am trying to get json response from the server. But jquery only got html. By the way I  am using zend framework. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: We need way more information than that. Show us some code!

Comment: You're going to have to show some code, doubt anyone can help with so little information.

Comment: Do you use the Zend_Application (MVC / Layout) ? You may need to disable view auto-rendering

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

or

```
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
```

and then output the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->_helper->json($myArray);
```

Will disable layout and handle everything including header for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:

You need to use `contextSwitch()` action helper, or disable the view and layout rendering and send the JSON *response* manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $json = Array(
    "name"=>"value"
  );
  header("Content-type: application/json");
  echo json_encode($json);
```